# Create a sign up form using lightning out

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-out

I want to create a component in an external website that will fetch some data from the user that he enters and store in an salesforce object. Is it possible to do this.
I have used the below code but it is not working :

CreateContactRecord.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="CreateContactRecord" 
                implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
                access="global" >

    <!-- Include Static Resource-->
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
                  scripts="/resource/bootstrap/js/jquery.js,/resource/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>

    <!-- Define Attribute-->
    <aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contact',
                         'FirstName': '',
                         'LastName': '',
                         'Email': '', 
                         'Birthdate': ''
                       }"/>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h3>Please Enter The Candidate Information</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <ui:inputText class="form-control" value="{!v.contact.FirstName}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <ui:inputText class="form-control" value="{!v.contact.LastName}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <ui:inputText class="form-control" value="{!v.contact.Email}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date Of Birth</label>
            <ui:inputText class="form-control" value="{!v.contact.Birthdate}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <ui:button class="btn btn-default" press="{!c.create}">Create</ui:button>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

ManageContact.app

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="CreateContactRecord"/>
</aura:application>
```

CreateContactRecord.apxc

```
public with sharing class CreateContactRecord {


    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createRecord (Contact contact){

        try{
            System.debug('CreateContactRecord::createRecord::contact'+contact);

            if(contact != null){
                insert contact;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex){

        }

    }    
}
```

and this is the code I've written in the website

```
<div id="lightning"></div>
<script src="https://atosauto-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
<script>
     $Lightning.use("c:ManageContact", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:CreateContactRecord", {
             objectName: "Contact"
            },
        },
       'https://atosauto-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/',

      );
</script>
```

I tried doing it in a Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

 <!-- This loads the JavaScript file needed to use Lightning Components for Visualforce-->
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <!-- div tag act as locator while calling Lightning.createComponent -->
    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>

        $Lightning.use("c:ManageContact", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:CreateContactRecord",
          "",
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        });

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

and for this it is showing the below error :

> An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 1851586357-376265
>   (989141424)

Comment: Can you provide more details on what is not working? Does it display an error? Does if not push data to the object? Does it make your computer explode?

Comment: Actually it is not displaying anything. It's just blank

Comment: @LukasLunow when I used Visualforce Page it gives the below error
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1851586357-376265 (989141424)

Comment: Any logs in the browser console?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://atosauto-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/c/ManageContact.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT' from origin 'https://lightningknow-developer-edition.ap5.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But I have whitelisted this in CORS settings

Answer (score 0):

Make the below change in your app for `<aura:dependency/>` tag

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
       <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:CreateContactRecord"/>
</aura:application>
```

In your visual force page make the below changes for the `parameters` instead of `""` change it to `{}`

```
    $Lightning.use("c:ManageContact", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:CreateContactRecord",
      {},
      "lightning",
      function(cmp) {
        // do some stuff
      });
    });

</script>
```

try above changes and let me know!!

Comment: I recieved this error: 
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1851586357-378069 (989141424)

Comment: Does the site guest user has access to contact and account object ?